# Is there a thing like HTTPContextEnricher thats works with Servicestack and Serilog

Tags: servicestack

I'm using Servicestack (.Core) and it's connection to Serilog. Is there a way to automatically enrich all Log-Entries with things like SessionId, UserId, etc.. The serilog-enrichers will not work due servicestack uses it's own session and user handling.

kind regards

Michael

Comment: This might be a better question for the servicestack forum.

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar configuration.
This code is called on `Application_Start`

```
if (Settings.SeqEnabled)
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestClientHostIPEnricher>()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestClientHostNameEnricher>()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestIdEnricher>()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestNumberEnricher>()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestRawUrlEnricher>()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestTraceIdEnricher>()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestTypeEnricher>()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestUrlEnricher>()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestUrlReferrerEnricher>()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestUserAgentEnricher>()
                .Enrich.With<HttpSessionIdEnricher>()
                .Enrich.With<ServiceStackUserNameEnricher>()
                .WriteTo.Seq(HostContext.AppSettings.GetString("SeqUrl"))
                .CreateLogger();
```

These enrichers are using SerilogWeb.Classic.Enrichers namespace.

ServiceStackUserNameEnricher is a class of mine.

```
public class ServiceStackUserNameEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    private const string UserNamePropertyName = "UserName";

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        if (logEvent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logEvent));
        string str;
        try
        {
            str = HttpContext.Current != null ? HostContext.GetCurrentRequest().GetSession().UserName : null;
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
        if (str == null)
            return;
        var property = new LogEventProperty(UserNamePropertyName, new ScalarValue(str));
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(property);
    }
}
```

Packages for Serilog

```
  <package id="Serilog" version="2.9.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Serilog.Formatting.Compact" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.File" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="SerilogWeb.Classic" version="5.0.52" targetFramework="net46" />
```