# ServiceStack structured logging

Tags: servicestack

How can I get structured logging when using e.g. Serilog with Servicestack?

The examples from both Serilog and NLog have the form `Log.Information("Hello World from {FirstName}", "Thomas");` for which I cannot find a matching method signature in ServiceStack.

Comment: There is `DebugFormat`, `InfoFormat`, `WarnFormat` and `ErrorFormat`

Comment: @RolfKristensen how do they work? Would `log.PushProperty("FirstName", "Thomas")` then `log.InfoFormat("Hello World from {FirstName}");` work? So I'd need to write two lines?

Comment: @speciman You asked for something that matched `Log.Information`. If you want something that matches `Log.PushProperty` then you should update your question.

Comment: @RolfKristensen - I did not see the xxxFormat methods in the docs, that got me confused. They are just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See logging docs for [enhanced Serilog Logging APIs](https://docs.servicestack.net/logging#serilog) whilst this [existing StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60147540/85785) shows a Serilog Enrichers example.

[SerilogLoggerTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Logging.Tests/UnitTests/SerilogLoggerTests.cs) shows different examples of using Serilog:

```
var log = new SerilogLogger(GetType());

const string message = "Error Message";
const string messageFormat = "Message Format: message: {0}, exception: {1}";

var ex = new Exception();
log.Info(message);
log.Info(message, ex);
log.InfoFormat(messageFormat, message, ex.Message);
log.Info(ex, messageFormat, messageFormat, ex);
```

and a Log Context example with custom properties:

```
var log = new SerilogLogger(new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Sink(sink).CreateLogger());

var messageTemplate = "Testing adding {prop2} props";
log.ForContext("prop", "value").InfoFormat(messageTemplate, "awesome");
```

There's also `PushProperty()` APIs to assign custom properties, see [Serilog's Enrichment docs](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext) for examples.

Comment: Already saw the docs, but did not understand. It seems they all need an exception to work, e.g. `ILog.Info(Exception ex, string messageTemplate, params object[] propertyValues)`. I don't have an exception, just want to log template + params. Can I pass `null` as the first param?

Comment: @specimen there are different overloads you can use, see updated answer.

Comment: I did not see the xxxFormat methods in the docs, that got me confused. They are just what I was looking for.